# Rails search form with multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search-form

I am working on a search form which should accept multiple params. But it currently accepts only one.

My Controller action:

```
def index
  @halls = Hall.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(9)
  @city = City.all
  @venue_type = VenueType.all
  @event_type = EventType.all

  if !params[:city].blank?
    session[:city] = params[:city]
    city = City.find_by(name: params[:city])
    @halls = @halls.where(:city => city)
  end

  if !params[:venue_types].blank?
    session[:venue_types] = params[:venue_types]
    venue_types = VenueType.find_by(name: params[:venue_types])
    @halls = @halls.where(:venue_types => venue_types)
  end

 if !params[:event_types].blank?
    session[:event_types] = params[:event_types]
    event_types = VenueType.find_by(name: params[:event_types])
    @halls = @halls.where(:event_types => event_types)
  end
```

end

My view:

```
<div class="search">
  <%= form_tag(halls_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>

<%= select_tag "city", options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, "name", "name") %>

          <ul>
            <% @venue_type.each do |venue| %>
                <li>
                  <%= check_box_tag 'venue_type[]', venue.name -%>
                  <%=  venue.name -%>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <% @event_type.each do |event| %>
                <li>
                  <%= check_box_tag 'event_type[]', event.name -%>
                  <%=  event.name -%>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>

      <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I bet the mistake is in the controller but as a newbie I can't find it.
Would be grateful for the answers.

Comment: try to print the `params` using `puts` in the `index` action and see whether you receive the correct params..

Answer (score 0):

Your view defined the check_box_tag with:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'venue_type[]', venue.name -%>
<%=  venue.name -%>

<%= check_box_tag 'event_type[]', event.name -%>
<%=  event.name -%>
```

As you see, your controller must get `:value_type` & `:event_type` from params instead of `:value_types` & `:event_types`. So you can change from either view or controller, it should work, but I recommend change from view like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'venue_types[]', venue.name -%>
<%=  venue.name -%>

<%= check_box_tag 'event_types[]', event.name -%>
<%=  event.name -%>
```

Comment: thanks. Did that. But still doesn't show results matching the search query.

Comment: Could you log your params & update to your question?